# Function seems to return the correct value, but the outside caller never gets it in C

Tags: c, function, queue, printf, getter

I implemented a queue using a linked list. I also created a getter that reads the data of any entry in this queue. When I call this function from a tester, I find that the value that is being returned as the value of the entry inside the queue is not the same as the one being read within the getter.

```
struct entry{
    double data;
    attribute_value time_stamp;
    struct entry* next;
};


typedef struct queue_struct{
    struct entry* front;
    struct entry* end;
    int size;
} queue;
```

The getter below takes in an entry of the queue and returns the value for the data structure variable, if the current entry is not null:

```
double get_data(struct entry *current){
    // The value is correct here
    printf("!!!!!!!!!!!!! %lf\n", current->data);
    if(current) return current->data; 
    return 0;
}
```

I use this helper to get the very first entry of the queue:

```
struct entry* get_front(queue *Q){
    return Q->front;
}
```

Here is the tester. It creates a queue (which simply allocates space for it and assigns first = NULL, end = NULL, and size = 0). Then it pushed value 10 to the queue. (Ignore the zero! It does not have anything to do with the data). Then, it prints the queue successfully by starting at its first element and printing the "data" variable until it hits a NULL element. Then, I ask it to print the data of the very first entry/element in the queue. This is where I get the wrong value.

```
void test_queue_push(bool enable_print){
    printf(TESTING, "Testing push in queue.c");
    queue* Q = construct_queue();

    push(Q, 10, 0);
    if(enable_print) print_queau(Q); // This prints the queue correctly!

    // The wrong value is printed here!
    printf("GET DATA: %lf\n", get_data(get_front(Q))); 
}
```

This tested prints out the following:

```
10.000000 ->                        // This is result of print_queue
!!!!!!!!!!!!! 10.000000             // This is data of first entry printed INSIDE the getter function itself
GET DATA: 0.000000                  // This is the returned data of first entry, printed inside the tester
```

I do not understand why I do not get the value "10.0000" for both - the second and third line.

> I just tried using "long long int" instead of "double" for the entry's data variable and all of the other functions. The error disappears if I use a different data type. No idea why.

Print queue also uses get_data function, and the first line of the print out reflects that get_data inside print_queue works just fine. Here is the function:

```
void print_queau(queue* Q) {
    struct entry* temp = get_front(Q);
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("%lf -> ", get_data(temp));
        temp = get_next(temp);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Just in case, this is what the push function looks like:

```
void push(queue* Q, double input, attribute_value time_stamp){
    if(Q){ //if Queue exists
    struct entry* in;   //create a new entry object
        if(in = calloc(1, sizeof(struct entry))){ //if allocating space for the entry object succeeds
            Q->size = Q->size + 1;
            in->data = input; //enter the input as its current data
            in->next = NULL; //set next to null because the end of the queue can have no next entry that follows it
            in->time_stamp = time_stamp; //set the time stamp to the Power On Hours on the system

            if(get_front(Q) == NULL && get_end(Q) == NULL){  //if front and end of the queue have not yet been set
                set_front(Q, in); //then this entry is both the front
                set_end(Q, in); //and the end
                return;
            }
            set_next(get_end(Q), in); //next value of the entry at the end is now our new entry
            set_end(Q, in);
            //printf("The End is: %i\n", Q->size);
        }
    }
}
```

Construct queue looks like this:

```
/*Constructor for the Queue structure instance
    @param none
    @return pointer to queue or NULL pointer in case of memory allocaion failure
*/
queue* construct_queue(){
    queue* Q;
    if(Q = calloc(1, sizeof(queue))){ 
        Q->front = NULL;  //at first the queue does not have any entries
        Q->end = NULL;    //therefore it has no front and no end
        Q->size = 0;      //its size starts off at zero to indicate that there are no entries.
    }
    if(Q == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Ran out of memory when allocating memory for queue in construct_queue in queue.c\n");
    }
    return Q;
}
```

I used the following code to build the code above: https://gist.github.com/mycodeschool/7510222

Comment: I don't think it is your problem, but `get_data()` isn't consistent - it prints `current->data` and then checks `current` - you should null check first - a) avoid undefined behavior, b) value printed will match value returned.

Comment: Can you please add the code for your construct_queue() function?

Comment: @ Lencho Reyes - I did!

@John3136 - I will try that right now.

Comment: Is `get_data()` declare/defined before first use?

Comment: You got it. I forgot to include it into the header. Many thanks! Please post it as the answer and I will select it.

Comment: You may post your own - time for my beauty sleep ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a lot of missing code that had to be reconstructed.  This code, which carefully ensures that all functions are declared before being used, seems to work correctly:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int attribute_value;

#define TESTING "%s\n"

struct entry
{
    double data;
    attribute_value time_stamp;
    struct entry *next;
};

typedef struct queue_struct
{
    struct entry *front;
    struct entry *end;
    int size;
} queue;

double get_data(struct entry *current);
queue *construct_queue(void);
struct entry *get_front(queue *Q);
struct entry *get_end(queue *Q);
void print_queau(queue *Q);
void push(queue *Q, double input, attribute_value time_stamp);
void test_queue_push(bool enable_print);
struct entry *get_next(struct entry *curr);
void set_front(queue *Q, struct entry *in);
void set_end(queue *Q, struct entry *in);
void set_next(struct entry *E, struct entry *in);

void set_front(queue *Q, struct entry *in)
{
    if (Q != 0)
        Q->front = in;
}

void set_end(queue *Q, struct entry *in)
{
    if (Q != 0)
        Q->end = in;
}

void set_next(struct entry *E, struct entry *in)
{
    if (E != 0)
        E->next = in;
}

struct entry *get_next(struct entry *curr)
{
    if (curr != 0)
        return curr->next;
    return 0;
}

double get_data(struct entry *current)
{
    if (current)
    {
        printf("!!!!!!!!!!!!! %lf\n", current->data);
        return current->data;
    }
    return 0;
}

struct entry *get_end(queue *Q)
{
    return Q->end;
}

struct entry *get_front(queue *Q)
{
    return Q->front;
}

void test_queue_push(bool enable_print)
{
    printf(TESTING, "Testing push in queue.c");
    queue *Q = construct_queue();

    push(Q, 10, 0);
    if (enable_print)
        print_queau(Q);


    printf("GET DATA: %lf\n", get_data(get_front(Q)));
}

void print_queau(queue *Q)
{
    struct entry *temp = get_front(Q);
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%lf -> ", get_data(temp));
        temp = get_next(temp);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void push(queue *Q, double input, attribute_value time_stamp)
{
    if (Q)
    {
        struct entry *in;
        if ((in = calloc(1, sizeof(struct entry))) != 0)
        {
            Q->size = Q->size + 1;
            in->data = input;
            in->next = NULL;
            in->time_stamp = time_stamp;

            if (get_front(Q) == NULL && get_end(Q) == NULL)
            {
                set_front(Q, in);
                set_end(Q, in);
                return;
            }
            set_next(get_end(Q), in);
            set_end(Q, in);
        }
    }
}

queue *construct_queue(void)
{
    queue *Q;
    if ((Q = calloc(1, sizeof(queue))) != 0)
    {
        Q->front = NULL;
        Q->end = NULL;
        Q->size = 0;
    }
    if (Q == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Ran out of memory when allocating memory for queue in construct_queue in queue.c\n");
    }
    return Q;
}

int main(void)
{
    test_queue_push(true);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Werror queue.c -o queue
$
```

That's GCC 5.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.10.4, with options set fussy and no warnings.  The 'prototypes' options ensure that functions are declared before they're defined or used — or are `static` functions.  I didn't make anything `static` here; I usually do when there's only a single source file.

Sample output:

```
Testing push in queue.c
!!!!!!!!!!!!! 10.000000
10.000000 -> 
!!!!!!!!!!!!! 10.000000
GET DATA: 10.000000
```

There is room to suppose that the problem was either in an absence of one or more function prototypes or a bug in one of the functions omitted.  Note that I fixed the code in `get_data()` so it does not crash if the `current` pointer is NULL — your code tried to print the value in `current->data` regardless of whether `current` was null or not (even though it then checked the value `current` — just a little too late).

Comment: To pinpoint the actual problem, as chux said and as you coded -  I did not include "get_data" in the header. Thanks for the thorough answer!